# Chrome Extension Rejection "Use of Permissions" All URLs

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

Hello Stack Overflow Team, I am hoping you can help.

The Google Chrome webstore as of 3/1/2020 is rejecting all my extensions that have activeTab permissions specifically `<all_urls>` requests. Below is the email I get AFTER my extensions are reviewed.

> Your item did not comply with the following section of our Program Policies:
>
> "User Data Privacy"
>
> Your product violates the "Use of Permissions" section of the policy, which requires that you:
>
> - Request access to the narrowest permissions necessary to implement your product’s features or services.
> - If more than one permission could be used to implement a feature, you must request those with the least access to data or functionality.
> - Don't attempt to "future proof" your product by requesting a permission that might benefit services or features that have not yet been implemented.

This is a HUGE problem because not only are all our recent apps being rejected, but so are the updates to our existing apps that are using the EXACT same permission set.

Our extensions connects business phone systems to Chrome and one of the features we offer is click to call. In order for click to call to work we need `<all_urls>` permissions so we can find phone number and make them clickable. Below is a sample of our code.

What changes do I need to make in order for Google Chrome to STOP rejecting our extensions?

```
{
"update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
"name": "abc extension",
"description": "abc company click to call",
"short_name": "abc click to call",
"version": "0.00.01",
"manifest_version": 2,
"permissions": [
    "storage",
    "notifications",
    "tabs",
    "contextMenus",
    "<all_urls>"
],
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
        "19": "images/icon.png"
    }
},
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com; object-src 'self'",
"default_locale": "en",
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches":["<all_urls>"],
        "css": [ "css/content.css" ],
        "js": ["js/jquery.min.js","js/content.js"],
        "run_at": "document_end"
    }
],
"background": {
    "scripts": ["js/jquery.min.js","js/background.js"]
},
"web_accessible_resources":["images/*.png","html/login.html","html/dashboard.html"],
"icons": {
    "16": "images/icon.png",
    "48": "images/icon.png"
}
```

Comment: There's nothing you can do other than castrating your app by removing all_urls and using activeTab instead so it works only after the user first clicks your extension icon or presses a customizable hotkey that you register via [commands](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands). Well, you can keep trying to convince the mindless drones in the web store, of course.

Comment: @wOxxOm I hear you LOUD and CLEAR with the mindless drones comment. I am not even convinced applications actually get reviewed by a person. I think they just hit a time threshold then get auto rejected if there is a line of code that says `<all_urls>`. I have sent in numerous support tickets and resubmitted apps TONs of times. What is weird is sometimes they get approved. I just don't get it. It is exhausting!

Comment: Hi! We have the same issue with an extension that has been live for a while and now all of a sudden gets rejected with the same notice. Google claims that we aren't using the  APIs that we request under "permissions" in the manifest but we sure as heck are. Are you using the "webextension-polyfill" package to make your extension cross browser? We are and my current theory is that Google checks our code for any occurrences of e.g. `chrome.identity` whereas we just call `identity` directly from the polyfill, which might cause the rejection. Would be very interested to hear your progress on this!

Comment: My extension got rejected suddenly with this exact reason. It has permissions `"storage", "tabs", "identity', "https://oneurl.com/*"`. I needed all of them, but I could manage without `storage`, even though it crippled extension a bit. And what do you know - without `storage` permission it got approved again. So you can try removing `storage` permission of use `cookies` instead (although this probably won't make any difference).

Comment: [Test Rest Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60727329/chrome-extension-rejection-use-of-permissions-all-urls)
test answer only can't take it serio